# disable textbox using jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable textbox using jquery like below but its not working

```
$("#docNumber").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

also tried beow but no luck

```
$("#docNumber").attr("disabled",true);
```

Below is code
http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/j6jZA/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is on your first line:

```
$(document).ready(
```

This must be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

And then finish off with:

```
});
```

See this update, works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j6jZA/7/

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `.ready` correctly in your fiddle `-->` *$(document).ready(*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 // disable the docNumber textbox when page is loaded
    $("#docNumber").prop("disabled",true);

});
```

Working demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/j6jZA/5/

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is correct, your DOM ready statement is wrong. Change to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//do stuff
});
```